# Best way to Merge 2 tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to merge two similar tables (not exact) to one table. Getting lots of errors Any ideas on best way to do this?

Comment: Like what kinds of errors?  And what does the schema look like?

Comment: is it SQL server 2008 (like in the title) or SQL Server 2005 (like the tag you added) ?

Comment: Without knowing the errors and/or schema of the tables involved this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Have a look at the two tables. http://prototype.lifetime.com/tablestructure.png

Comment: 2008 not 2005 sorry. I would like to merge tblDVpagecategory to tbldvpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there is not a Type field in tblDVPage to hold tblDVpagecategory.type, if you wanted to merge the latter into the former, so you may need to create a new column for it, or hold tblDVpagecategory.type with tblDVPage.pageType.

Either ways you will end up having something similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO tblDVPage(Title, ParentId, PageType, MenuOrder)
SELECT Title, ParentId, Type, MenuOrder
FROM tblDVpagecategory
```

Obviously your old IDs in tblDVpagecategory will be gone, and regenerated when the items are merged into tblDVPage. If you might want to differentiate what is what with a new column, but depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered:

1. Create a view to join the two tables with a where clause limiting the number of rows for quicker execution during the design of the view
2. After the view is correct do a "select into" with a where condition of 1=2.  This will give you an empty table with column names and data types from the view
3. Edit the table design to include identity column, adjust data types, column names, etc
4. Insert data from the view into the table
5. Create indexes and FK as necessary
6. Rename tables if necessary
7. Drop the view

Beware of transaction log growth

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused you tag the question SQL Server 2005, but you ask about 2008? If you are really using 2008, try using [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), which is only available on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: my t-sql is a bit lacking to say the least